# In a permissioned blockchain network can a participant from one network transact with a participant in another network?

Tags: quorum

In my setup, each organization (organization A and organization B) has own quorum network.
Participant of organization A wants to transact with a participant in organization B.

Can it be achieved? I am following an example from [this](https://github.com/bacen/quorum-examples/tree/master/examples/5nodesRTGS).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`Quorum` is a permissioned blockchain network. So all the participants that want to transact each other should be in the same blockchain network. I don't think it will be possible to transfer amount from the participant of blockchain network of organization A to the participant of blockchain network of organization B if they are having their own blockchain network.

Comment: Thank you for the reply. If I create single Quorum permissioned blockchain network for Organization A and Organization B, how will I be able to set a boundary between two organizations? Can I keep regulators separate for each organization?

Comment: Refer to following post,I hope it will help you to understand concepts https://medium.com/@didil/enterprise-ethereum-private-transactions-with-quorum-b0574bb60700